# Union type in object keys supresses errors in typescript

Tags: typescript

Lets have a function

```
type UnionType = 'option1' | 'option2'
const myFunction = (arg: Partial<Record<UnionType, number>>) => {
  console.log(arg)
}
```

calling it with argument of wrong type

```
myFunction({option1: 1, ['option3' as 'option3']: 2})
```

results in an error
`Argument of type '{ option1: number; option3: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Partial<Record<UnionType, number>>'. Object literal may only specify known properties, and '['option3' as 'option3']' does not exist in type 'Partial<Record<UnionType, number>>'`

This is expected. However if we change the type of the `option3` argument to an union type, the error vanishes, which is unexpected.
This raises no error:

```
myFunction({option1: 1, ['option3' as 'option3' | 'option4']: 2})
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

This is a current limitation or missing feature of TypeScript.  Computed property keys whose types aren't single string [literals](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) get widened all the way to `string` and thus the object gets an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) most people don't expect.

Observe the inferred type of your object literal:

```
const v = { option1: 1, ['option3' as 'option3' | 'option4']: 2 };
/* const v: {
    [x: string]: number;
    option1: number;
} */
```

That means the compiler thinks that `v` might have all kinds of property keys, all of which would have a `number` value, and therefore `v` is assignable to `{option1?: number, option2?: number}`:

```
myFunction(v); // okay
```

See [microsoft/TypeScript#13948](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13948) and [microsoft/TypeScript#38663](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38663) for more information and an authoritative source.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgSwPZwCrmgXigciWYZOARhygB9d9CUAmHAWACgBjFAZ2CgFsQAxAK5wWNOFGwAKAIYAnAOYAuKAAVZhKQBsAPACUIbGQBMt8IukgAaKHAHcARhBkA+JwEpxTqAG9mUP1DY4diQNCAA6DSQ5aXlXZgBfZkDOKAA3cW8oaiJiJWIrAG08AiIAZjIpdioSlHKKatEAFhwAXSVaKHiAbmYAegAqAI4uVKUfJn8oAoAPJU4ZBDg5NutbBxkeif9slFzV+0dN+Kh+3uZeQWFRCVTXIA)